# open terminal from a terminal and execute commands from it

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command-line

I want to open multiple terminals using one command in one terminal. I then want the child terminals to execute certain commands.

I am able to open the child terminals but can't execute any commands

I tried

```
for i in {1,2,3}; do echo -e "======opening terminal $i ===\n"; gnome-terminal ping localhost $i --wait;done
```